# Cannot install Angular cli on centos 7

Tags: node.js, angular

When I install Angular on Centos 7 on the command line:

```
npm install -g @angualr/cli
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-/iZaIYrGpXz+hUkn6dBMGYJe3es= integrity checksum failed 
when using sha1: wanted sha1-/iZaIYrGpXz+hUkn6dBMGYJe3es= but got sha1-
zgHXh1Cn13OgmB5vLEBAbNeJQqU=. (92956 bytes)
```

I am using these versions:

> npm 5.0.0
>
> node.js 8.0.0

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem on ubuntu and i solved this issue by downgrading npm to v4.6 , i hope it solves yours